# SSRS 2008 - Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, ssas, reporting-services, ssas-2008

Issue I get for one of my shared data sets only on certain parameters. If the parameter returns nothing for that dataset then I seem to come across this problem, there is a tablix in this report that uses the shared dataset and if I remove the tablix but keep the shared dataset I still get the error on the report preview.

The dataset uses a MDX query (SSAS) to get its data, if I run the query from the query designer it returns 2 rows but the dates in the rows are outwith the scope of my report so the report would return 0 and I assume thats my issue.

Anyone got any ideas/tips?

Uses SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get round this issue by having an embedded data set rather than a shared one.

Gets around the issue, very annoying though!